# Is the new Baki anime series (ONA) a continuation of the manga, or the same story as the old anime with better animation?

Tags: grappler-baki

I am referring to the new Baki (ONA) released in 2018.

Is it a continuation of the manga, or the same story as the old anime with better animation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It takes place directly after the events of the original Anime. If you've  seen the original then you can just continue from the end of that but even if you haven't, then you can still just start with it since the majority of the plot is only loosely stapled together by a few characters.